# Nested Data Tables: They said it can not be done?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying unsuccessfully to do something that I would have thought in WPF should be quite easy.

We wanted to display a table in a cell of another table recursively (that can be expanded / collapsed). (Not Master / Detail, but true tree like recursion into the sub-tables)

We thought maybe a DataGrid or a GridView might be able to achive this but we've been unsucessful in our attempts, so I wanted to check with the world at large that we're trying to do something possible.

If it helps, it's readonly data, but it's all data-driven so there's a dynamic number of rows and columns.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I've seen something like this done in asp.net and it looked quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need a hierarchical data grid, evaluate [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/grids-and-lists/data-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the DataGrid's RowDetailsTemplate. You should be able to add whatever you want in there including another Grid.